# Why does balanceof() return a constant?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, balances, constant

The ERC20 token standard specifies `balanceof()` to return a `constant`.

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance)
```

But the balance amount might change or am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The constant keyword does not specify what the function returns.
A function marked as constant like this one tells you that the function will return a value and will not modify any state variables. A large use for the constant/view keywords is to declare a function that can be called without sending a transaction, i.e. a free "query" of the blockchain.

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#view-functions

Comment: Why would it be wrong not to use `constant` in `balanceof()`? The function itself doesn't change any state, it only returns `return balances[_owner];`

Comment: It wouldn't be wrong. You're right to have constant there.

Comment: What is "constant" is the function, which in Solidity refers to a function that doesn't modify the state of the blockchain, just reads values.
Not to be confused with a constant variable, whose value can't be changed once declared.

Answer (score 1):

constant on functions is an alias to view, so when executed you can view the contents that function returns